# group the values of an array into another array php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array like this:

```
$lista = array (
    0 => array ( 'id_dcmnto_rdcdo' => 2, 'dcmnto_rfrnca' => 100 ),
    1 => array ( 'id_dcmnto_rdcdo' => 1 ,'dcmnto_rfrnca' => 104 ),
    2 => array ( 'id_dcmnto_rdcdo' => 1 ,'dcmnto_rfrnca' => 105 ),
    3 => array ( 'id_dcmnto_rdcdo' => 3 ,'dcmnto_rfrnca' => 110 ),
    4 => array ( 'id_dcmnto_rdcdo' => 3 ,'dcmnto_rfrnca' => 111 ),
    5 => array ( 'id_dcmnto_rdcdo' => 3 ,'dcmnto_rfrnca' => 112 ),
    6 => array ( 'id_dcmnto_rdcdo' => 3 ,'dcmnto_rfrnca' => 113 ),
    7 => array ( 'id_dcmnto_rdcdo' => 3 ,'dcmnto_rfrnca' => 120 ),
    8 => array ( 'id_dcmnto_rdcdo' => 3 ,'dcmnto_rfrnca' => 123 ),
    9 => array ( 'id_dcmnto_rdcdo' => 3 ,'dcmnto_rfrnca' => 125 )
);
```

how can i do to transform this array in another array grouped by dcmnto_rfrnca like this:

```
array(
    [0]=>'100',
    [1]=>'104-105',
    [2]=>'110-113',
    [3]=>'120',
    [4]=>'123',
    [5]=>'125'
);
```

i have this code but doest not work :s

```
foreach ($lista as $clave => $fila) {


        $rfrnca = $fila['dcmnto_rfrnca'];
        $dcmnto_rfrnca_ms_uno = $fila['dcmnto_rfrnca']+1;
        $dcmnto_rfrnca_prxmo = $lista[$i+1]['dcmnto_rfrnca'];


        if ($dcmnto_rfrnca_prxmo==$dcmnto_rfrnca_ms_uno){
            $ll_consecutivo = true;
        }else{
            $ll_consecutivo = false;
            array_push($cnslddo,$rfrnca);
        }

        echo ' ref anterior anterior '.$rfrnca.' - siguiente ' . $dcmnto_rfrnca_prxmo;
        echo 'masuno ' . $dcmnto_rfrnca_ms_uno . ' - consecutivo '. $ll_consecutivo .' <br>';

        $i++;

echo $fila['dcmnto_rfrnca'] . '<br>'}echo '<br><br><hr>';print_r($cnslddo);
```

Comment: Can you explain the intended basis for the grouping? How do you derive when to create entries like `104-105` or `110-113`?

Comment: these should be grouped by row for example if I have:
200,201,202,203,205,206,300,301,302 this should be grouped as follows ("200-201-202-203", "205-206", "300-301-302");

Comment: Are you sure your example is correct?
If you mean to group by `id_dcmnto_rdcdo`, then your result doesn't look correct, i.e.:
Where do you get the following entries:
`0 => 100, 
4 => 123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First one:

```
$a = array();
$t = '';

foreach ($lista as $i => $value) {

    if ($t == '') $t = $value['dcmnto_rfrnca'];
    if (isset($lista[$i+1])) {

        if (((int)$value['dcmnto_rfrnca']+1) == (int)$lista[$i+1]['dcmnto_rfrnca']) {

            $t .= '-'.$lista[$i+1]['dcmnto_rfrnca'];

        }
          else {$a[] = $t; $t = '';}
    } 
      else {$a[] = $t; $t = '';}
}
```

**output:**

```
Array 
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 104-105
    [2] => 110-111-112-113
    [3] => 120
    [4] => 123
    [5] => 125 
)
```

### Second one:

```
$a = array();
$t = '';

foreach ($lista as $i => $value) {

    if ($t == '') $t = $value['dcmnto_rfrnca'];

    if (isset($lista[$i+1])) {

        if (((int)$value['dcmnto_rfrnca']+1) != (int)$lista[$i+1]['dcmnto_rfrnca']) {

            if ($t != $value['dcmnto_rfrnca']) $t .= '-'.$value['dcmnto_rfrnca']; 
            $a[] = $t; 
            $t = '';

        }

    } 
      else {$a[] = $t; $t = '';}
}
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 104-105
    [2] => 110-113
    [3] => 120
    [4] => 123
    [5] => 125
)
```

Comment: tnx bro awesome this is what i need :D